# DocuSign add custom email message, subject, and language when sending envelope using POST request

Tags: docusignapi

Using the following POST request and body to send an envelope (source https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/how-to/request-signature-template-remote)

```
https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2.1/accounts/4f4xxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxx/envelopes

{
  "templateId": "dbexxxx-xxxxx-xxxxx",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "test@gmail.com",
      "name": "John Doe",
      "roleName": "signer1",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "cname",
            "value": "name"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "status": "sent"
}
```

Is there a way to specify the email message, email subject and/or email language? I tried adding `"emailSubject": "Please sign ..."` next to *"email"* but cannot seem to make it work. It is a requirement that I need to manually make this post request so I cannot use the SDK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where you placing the "emailSubject" field exactly in your JSON?

You can specify the the email message and subject by specifying the following fields at the root level (where you "status" is defined):

```
{
    "emailBlurb": "げりト画首ロ百照ょリっ毎現イタヱア掲全らいに",
    "emailSubject": "Subject of agreement",
    "templateId": "867a37*****",
    "templateRoles": [
        {
            "email": "email@domain.com",
            "name": "name_of_person",
            "roleName": "Seller"
        }
    ],
    "status": "sent"
}
```